# EEVEE _ deactivate lamp on rendering with volumetric fog, and keep only the illumination

Tags: rendering, lighting, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

I m working a scene on EEVEE, and I had placed some extra spot lights to illuminate my focus object. Also I have used volumetric fog. I need to keep the illumination of those spot lights but not the source of the lights. cause combined with volumes it creates a tiny lighting center. I need to remove those from the rendering. there is a way to do it? I can do something similar by the settings of volume,    that volume start at a fixed distance from the camera. but at this scene it doesn't fit cause the volume needs to be close to the camera. Do you have any idea?
Thank you very much!
I m looking forward for an answer!
Best Regards
Ilias

Comment: Welcome to BSE. Please provide one or two images to illustrate the problem you're facing and the result you are looking for. Also please keep in mind that this site only accepts one question at a time.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add images that might help us understand your scene and settings. ( to learn how to post images [read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491))